# Changing speed of D3 path animation

Tags: animation, d3.js

Here is the code:
http://jsfiddle.net/fJAwW/

This is what I am interested in:

```
path
  .attr("stroke-dasharray", totalLength + " " + totalLength)
  .attr("stroke-dashoffset", totalLength)
  .transition()
    .duration(2000)
    .ease("linear")
    .attr("stroke-dashoffset", 0);
```

I have my data variable lineData, which I add to the path with

```
.attr("d", line(lineData))
```

For the transition section:

```
  .transition()
    .duration(2000)
```

I would like to do something like

```
  .transition()
    .duration(function(d) {
      return d.x;
    })
```

Where d is one of my data points.

I am having trouble understanding the data structures and how they interact in d3.js, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you mean that you want the animation to move faster or slower at different points along the line, e.g. based on whether it's going "uphill" or "downhill"?

Comment: Yeah basically.  Eventually I'd like to have my data like { x:1, y:2, speed: 50 }, and be able to control the transition between points with the speed attribute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One interesting thing about `d3` is that data isn't stored in the `d` attribute, it's in the `__data__` attribute. Paths are special in that *this isn't actually where the data about the path is stored.* While it's possible to circumvent it, I would highly recommend using the standard `d3` data pattern, with `.data()`, `.enter()`, and `.append()`.

Because you never actually enter any data, `__data__` is empty, and, as a result, `d` is undefined if you use `.duration(function(d) {})`.

In general, when you pass a function like that, the variable itself doesn't matter. The first variable is always assigned to `__data__` for the selection and the second is always the index.

Probably the best example of the update pattern is [this block](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3808218) by Mike Bostock. There's also some great info in the API if you get stuck, as well as about ten billion tutorials on how to make a scatter plot that all say about the same thing.

You can use `.data()` to put some data in your path, and then access it with a function in `.duration()`, like so:

```
path.data([{'duration':1000}])
    .transition()
    .duration(function(d){return d.duration})
```

Comment: If I'm reading it correctly, what you propose lets him change the speed per path, but he is trying to change the speed between points within a path.

Comment: Correct! Sort of. The problem is that the data entered into a path is only really accessible through `path[0][0].pathSegList.getItem(i)`, which will give you a specific path segment that is somewhat incomprehensible. If you want to access the points on the path, those points can be placed in `d`, with `path.data([lineData])` (note that, sans brackets, only the first point will end up in data.) Those points could then be used to set a custom easing function that would vary speed with place on path using a `function(d){}`. This way, you aren't hard coding data names anywhere.

Answer (score 5):

I believe you will need to create a set of chained transitions for changing the `stroke-dashoffset` value at each point in your line. As @ckersch pointed out, path is different than most things in d3 because the data is collapsed into a single path string rather than represented as individual values.

You can chain the initial transition from the `path` variable like you have done, and then chain the further transitions from the prior one. Something like this:

```
  // Add the path
  var path = svg.append('path')
    .attr( {d: line(lineData), stroke: "steelblue", 'stroke-width': 2, fill: 'none'} );

  var totalLength = path.node().getTotalLength();

  // start with the line totally hidden
  path.attr( {'stroke-dasharray': totalLength + " " + totalLength, 'stroke-dashoffset': totalLength } );

  // transition will be chained from either the original path or the last transition
  var transitionFrom = path;
  // start at 1 since no transition needed to first point
  for (var i = 1; i < lineData.length; i++) {
    transitionFrom = transitionFrom.transition()
      .duration(lineData[i].speed)
      .ease("linear")
      .attr("stroke-dashoffset", lengthAt[i-1] || 0);
  };
```

Where does this `lengthAt` array come from? Yeah that's the ugly part. My geometry skills are not good enough to know offhand how to approximate that to match the 'cardinal' interpolation in your line generator function, but in this example I've hacked up a way to do it by drawing hidden lines and reading it back out of svg:

http://bl.ocks.org/explunit/6082362

Comment: Thanks for the example. Did you ever figure out if there is some way to get subsections of the path instead of creating hidden lines?