# D3 fading SVG path animation

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

Could someone please show me how to fade out older path segments in this D3 SVG animation:

http://jsbin.com/zegim/2/edit

This example is fading out the entire path in 10 seconds, but would like to see how to do it for the path segments (and then remain faded). I added this line:

path.append('svg:animate') .attr('attributeName', 'opacity') .attr('from', '1') .attr('to', '0') .attr('dur', 10);

The example is the same code from this question:
  [Changing speed of D3 path animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17843494/changing-speed-of-d3-path-animation)
  http://bl.ocks.org/explunit/6082362

Thanks!

Comment: To do this, `stroke-dasharray` won't work -- you'll need to have separate `path` elements.

Comment: Ok, thanks for that info. The problem then is that will make the visualization even slower. Currently I already see a significant slowdown when I draw over 100 of these SVG paths in my script. I should probably do this in canvas then. With canvas I could just make add a rectangle on each frame that increases the alpha transparency. Yet I don't understand how to do this D3 example with canvas using the transition and easing functions of D3. I will ask this in another question.