# Animate multi line plot with variable speed in D3

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to animate multiple paths, where each path draws at a variable speed as it passes through subsequent sections. The paths should start drawing at the same time (but could end at different times). I'm using [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17843494/changing-speed-of-d3-path-animation) as a reference, but it only draws one line.

I have each path drawn separately and the lengths of each line segment, but the animation doesn't start and I don't think I'm accessing the speeds correctly in the last few lines.

[Here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nancynancy/8e0wmL9s/) for a full view, but the salient part is below. What's going wrong here?

```
var lengthAt = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

  start = i;
  end = i + 2;

  var path = svg.selectAll(".line")
    .data(lineData)
    .enter().append("path")
    .attr("d", function (d) { return line(d.values.slice(start, end)) })
    .style("stroke", "red")
    .style("stroke-width", .5)
   // .attr("class", "temppath")
   // .attr("visibility", "hidden");

  // get length at each segment 
  lengthAt.push([path["_groups"][0][0].getTotalLength(),
                 path["_groups"][0][1].getTotalLength()])
};

//svg.selectAll('.temppath').remove();
console.log({ lengthAt }) // looks good!

// Add the full path
var path = svg.selectAll(".line")
    .data(lineData)
    .enter()
    .append("path")
    .attr("d", function (d) { return line(d.values) })
    .style("stroke", "black")
    .attr('stroke-width', 2)
    .attr("fill", 'none');

// get the lengths of each path
var totalLength = [path["_groups"][0][0].getTotalLength(),
                   path["_groups"][0][1].getTotalLength()]

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/////////////////// START THE ANIMATION PROCESS /////////////////////

path.attr('stroke-dasharray', totalLength + " " + totalLength)
        .attr('stroke-dashoffset', totalLength)

var transitionFrom = path;

// start at 1 since no transition needed to first point
// iterate through "transitionFrom" and chain from point to 
// point, using the speed from the data.
for (var i = 1; i < 4; i++) {

  console.log(i)
  console.log(lengthAt[i - 1])
  lineData.forEach(function(d){ console.log(d.values[i].speed)})

  transitionFrom = transitionFrom.transition()
    .duration(function (d) { return d.values[i].speed })
    .ease(d3.easeLinear)
    .attr("stroke-dashoffset", lengthAt[i - 1] || 0)
}
```

Comment: `_groups` is not part of the public API, do not use it

Comment: Noted; how else should one access the lengths of these segments?

Comment: If I use path.node().getTotalLength() then I only get the first path's lengths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this problem is two parts. Firstly, I refactored to make use of forEach() and each() instead of loops. The independent/parametrized animation is done with use of chained transitions.

```
 // start the circle along the path
 var transitionFrom = circle.transition()
        .duration(eachGuy[1].speed)
        .attrTween("transform", getPath(mySegments[0].node()));

  // iterate through every segment and chain the transitions
  for (i = 1; i < 3; i++) {
    transitionFrom = transitionFrom.transition()
      .duration(eachGuy[i + 1].speed)
      .attrTween("transform", getPath(mySegments[i].node()))
  }

  // This is based off of Mike Bostock's example (linked below)
  function getPath(path) {
    var l = path.getTotalLength();
    return function () {
      return function (t) {
        var p = path.getPointAtLength(t * l);
        return "translate(" + p.x + "," + p.y + ")";
      };
    };
  };
```

Full fiddle is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/nancynancy/8e0wmL9s/).

Resources:

- [Mike Bostock's Point-Along-Path interpolation example](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1705868)
- If you are progressively animating a line, [this question](http://bl.ocks.org/explunit/6082362) might point you in
  the right direction.